# Rudin functional analysis theorem 2.5.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm reading through the Banach-Steinhaus, there are few bits I don't get.

The proof starts as

> Pick balanced neighborhoods $W,U$ of $0$ in $Y$ such that $\bar{U} + \bar{U} \subset W$.

I can pick balanced neighborhoods because of theorem 1.14 (any neighborhood contains a balanced neighborhood). But why I can choose $U$ such that $\bar{U} + \bar{U} \subset W$?

Other bit I struggle is the following

> If $x \in B$ then $\Gamma(x) \subset nU$ for some $n$, so that $x \in nE$ consequently $B \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} nE$.

Here $E$ is defined as

$$
E = \bigcap_{\Lambda \in \Gamma} \Lambda^{-1}(\bar{U})
$$

Now.. $x \in B$ means $\Gamma(x)$ is bounded, which implies in can *scale* $U$ with an integer $n$ in such a way that $\Gamma(x) \in nU$ (It's almost the definition of boundness but there's the bit "why I can use $U$ to bound $\Gamma(x)$m since $U$ is balanced"). Also why does it follows that $x \in nE$?

Answer (score 1):

The map $(x,y) \to x+y$ is continuous and the point $(0,0)$ is mapped to $0$ under this map. Since $W$ is a  neighborhood $o$  there exists an open set $V$ containing $(0,0)$ such that $(x,y) \in V$ implies $x+y \in W$. By the definition of  product  topology there exists a neighborhood $S$ of $0$ such that $S \times S \subset V$, It follows now that $S+S \subset W$. Now you can choose an open set $U$ containing $0$ such that $\overset {-} U \subset S$. [This entire sequence of steps is there in the book; perhaps you are jumping to this theorem before reading the earlier theorems].  This gives $\overset {-} U+\overset {-} U\subset W$. Second question: $\Gamma (x)\subset nU$ implies $\Lambda (x) \in nU$ for any $\Lambda \in \Gamma$ so $\Lambda (\frac  x n) \in U$. This implies $\frac x n \in E$ so $x \in nE$.

Comment: How do you go from $\bar{U} \subset S$ to $\bar{U} + \bar{U} \subset W$?

Comment: $\overset {-} U +\overset {-} U \subset S+S$ and $S+S \subset W$.

Comment: Where is the balanced used here?

Comment: Actually, balanced neighborhoods are not required in the proof.

Comment: Proof of what? The whole theorem or the bit I don't understand?

Comment: In the whole theorem.

Comment: Is it a mistake then? Or picking a balanced neighborhood makes life somehow easier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83984/discussion-between-kavi-rama-murthy-and-user8469759).

Comment: Which earlier theorem shows that we can find such a $\overline U \subseteq S$?