# Theorem 2.5 Rudin functional analysis, use of balanced neighbors.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940459/rudin-functional-analysis-theorem-2-5) (I sometimes read through the book to refresh my background in functional analysis).

The theorem starts with picking balanced neighbours $U$, $W$ such that
$$
\bar{U} + \bar{U} \subset W
$$

But the conclusion of the theorem is reached through the chains of inclusions

$$
\Lambda(V) \subset \Lambda x - \Lambda (E) \subset \bar{U} - \bar{U} \subset W
$$

I'm comparing $\bar{U} + \bar{U} \subset W$ against $\bar{U} - \bar{U} \subset W$. In chapter 1 the definition of balanced is:

> A set $B \subset X$ (topological vector space) is said to be balanced if $\alpha B \subset B$ for every $\alpha \in \Phi$ with $|\alpha| \leq 1$.

Therefore I suppose we have the inclusion $- \bar{U} \subset \bar{U}$ (since $|-1|\leq 1$) and therefore

$$
\bar{U} - \bar{U} \subset \bar{U} + \bar{U}
$$

However my question is whether or not is $- \bar{U} \subset \bar{U}$ or $- \bar{U} = \bar{U}$, I think the latter is the definition of symmetric set.

Comment: As $U$ is balanced, then $-U=U$.

Answer (score 1):

$-B \subset B$ if $B$ is balanced. This actually implies $-B=B$. Now $x \to -x$ is a homeomorphism so $- (\overline {U})=\overline {(-U)}=\overline {U}$.

Comment: So can I say "if $U$ is balanced then $U$ is symmetric" but not viceversa?

Comment: @user8469759 Certainly. Balanced sets are symmetric.